# no muestra propiedad vacía en json de una clase con jackson java

Tags: java, json, jackson

tengo un problema con la librería jackson tengo una clase que esta compuesta por, primer_nombre, segundo_nombre, primer_apillido y segundo_apellido pero en el momento que uno de estos llega vacío, no me aparece esa propiedad en el JSON generado.

```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    PersonasDTO result = mapper.readValue(json, PersonasDTO.class);
```

al enviar todos los datos el json generado queda así:

```
{"primer_nombre":"juan", "segundo_nombre": "carlos", "primer_apillido":"perez", "segundo_apellido": "martinez"}
```

pero si no envio el ejemplo el segundo_nombre me lo genera asi:

```
{"primer_nombre":"juan", "primer_apillido":"perez", "segundo_apellido": "martinez"}
```

y lo necesito que llegue vacío, así:

```
{"primer_nombre":"juan", "segundo_nombre": "", "primer_apillido":"perez", "segundo_apellido": "martinez"}
```

no encuentro la solución

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres que salgan los nulos cuando no tiene valor toca anotar tu clase con:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) 
public class PersonasDTO {
```

Si tu jackson es de una verison menor a la 2 debes usar

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
```

Si solo o quieres una sola vez agrega lo siguiente a tu mapper

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```